# How to get max of counts for groupby (most frequent items)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, max

I have a dataframe. I want to group by rows on some columns and then form a count column and then get the max of counts and create a column for it and attach it to dataframe.

I tried:

```
    df["max_pred"] = df.groupby(['fid','prefix','pred_text1'], 
                             sort=False)["pred_text1"].transform("max")
```

However it lists a row with max repeat for `pred_text1`, but I want the number of reparation for it

For example:

```
A  B  C
a  d  b
a  d  b
a  d  b
a  d  a
a  d  a
b  b  c
b  b  c
b  b  d
```

If I group the rows by A and B and then count C and get its max for each group and store that in new column F, I expect:

```
A  B  F   E
a  d  3   b
a  d  3   b
a  d  3   b
a  d  3   b
a  d  3   b
b  b  2   c
b  b  2   c
b  b  2   c
```

E shows the most frequent item whose frequency was specified in F

Comment: please provide an explicit reproducible input/output example

Comment: @mozway I modified my example, I want the whole df with new column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df['F'] = (df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['C']
             .transform(lambda g: g.value_counts(sort=False).max())
          )
```

Variant with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

df['F'] = (df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['C']
             .transform(lambda g: max(Counter(g).values()))
          )
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  F
0  a  d  b  3
1  a  d  b  3
2  a  d  b  3
3  a  d  a  3
4  a  d  a  3
5  b  b  c  2
6  b  b  c  2
7  b  b  d  2
```

##### update

I would use a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) here:

```
cols = ['A', 'B']
out = df.merge(df[cols+['C']]
                 .value_counts().groupby(cols).head(1)
                 .reset_index(name='F').rename(columns={'C': 'E'})
               )
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  E  F
0  a  d  b  b  3
1  a  d  b  b  3
2  a  d  b  b  3
3  a  d  a  b  3
4  a  d  a  b  3
5  b  b  c  c  2
6  b  b  c  c  2
7  b  b  d  c  2
```

Comment: Sorry, I modified the question a bit, I also want a column for the item with max value (in my Example column E). I thought my own solution will produce it but it doesn't.

Comment: what is is used for value_counts? Anywans currently it returns empty dataframe for my case

Comment: I guess a solution like the first one by adding new columns may have less problems in fitting my dataframe

Comment: Check the update, you likely have more columns

Answer (score 2):

Another option is with `get_dummies`; for large enough data, I'd expect @mozway's solution to scale better:

```py
temp = (pd
       .get_dummies(df, columns = ['C'], prefix="",prefix_sep="")
       .groupby(['A','B'])
       .transform('sum'))
(df
.drop(columns='C')
.assign(F=temp.max(1), E = temp.idxmax(1))
)
   A  B  F  E
0  a  d  3  b
1  a  d  3  b
2  a  d  3  b
3  a  d  3  b
4  a  d  3  b
5  b  b  2  c
6  b  b  2  c
7  b  b  2  c
```

Comment: thanks, I get `TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype`

Comment: what version of Pandas is this? I am on pandas 1.5.2, and not getting such error with the data you shared

Comment: yes, update will resolves the problem, yet doesn't produce the answer on my actual dataframe. Maybe I have to work on it, however, the other answer already works. Thanks!